# Simple Python text file Parser and Converter

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I wrote a simple text parser and a converter using Python 3.12.1.

The purpose is to read a text file that contains 20000 words one per line, and create an output file that contains all the queries.

Here is a snippet of the input file with fake values:

```
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
cccccccc
dddddddd
```

I got this file from an external source and I need to save those words in a database. For that reason, I need to read the input file and create the SQL queries. I can directly run the queries on the DB, but for simplicity, here I published a version with a text file for output.

I tried to implement the separation of concerns and the single responsability concept.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class ParserInterface(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def parse(self) -> None:
        pass

class ConverterInterface(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def convert(self, tablename: str = '', columnname: str = '') -> None:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def writeOnFile(self, filename: str = '') -> None:
        pass

class Parser(ParserInterface):

    def __init__(self, filename: str = '') -> None:
        if not filename:
            raise Exception('Filename cannot be empty!')
        self.filename = filename
        self.tokens = set()
        
    def parse(self) -> None:
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as file:
            while line := file.readline():
                self.tokens.add(line.rstrip())

class TextToMySQLConverter(ConverterInterface):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.tokens = set()
        self.queries = set()

    def setTokens(self, tokens: set = set()) -> None:
        self.tokens = tokens

    def convert(self, tablename: str = '', columnname: str = '') -> None:
        if not tablename:
            raise Exception('Tablename cannot be empty!')
        if not columnname:
            raise Exception('Columnname cannot be empty!')
        for token in self.tokens:
            query = 'INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ("{2}");'.format(tablename, columnname, token)
            self.queries.add(query)

    def writeOnFile(self, filename: str = '') -> None:
        if not filename:
            raise Exception('Filename cannot be empty!')
        with open(filename,'w') as file:
            for query in self.queries:
                file.write('{0}\n'.format(query))

class Manager:

    def __init__(self, parser: ParserInterface = None, converter: ConverterInterface = None) -> None:
        if not parser:
            raise Exception('Parser cannot be None!')
        if not converter:
            raise Exception('Converter cannot be None!')
        self.parser = parser
        self.converter = converter
        self.outputFilename = ''
        self.tableName = ''
        self.columnName = ''

    def setOutputFilename(self, filename: str = '') -> None:
        if not filename:
            raise Exception('Filename cannot be empty!')
        self.outputFilename = filename

    def setTableName(self, tableName: str = '') -> None:
        if not tableName:
            raise Exception('Filename cannot be empty!')
        self.tableName = tableName

    def setColumnName(self, columnName: str = '') -> None:
        if not columnName:
            raise Exception('Filename cannot be empty!')
        self.columnName = columnName

    def process(self):
        self.parser.parse()
        tokens = self.parser.tokens

        converter.setTokens(tokens)
        converter.convert(self.tableName, self.columnName)

        converter.writeOnFile(self.outputFilename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = Parser('original.txt')
    converter = TextToMySQLConverter() # We can implement a strategy here

    manager = Manager(parser, converter)
    manager.setOutputFilename('queries.txt')
    manager.setTableName("tablename")
    manager.setColumnName("columname")
    manager.process()
```

Comment: As I wrote in the description, the input file is a file that contains 20000 words one per line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Naming

Method/function names, parameters, and variable names should be `snake_case`

### `Parser.parse`

This doesn't have to be a `while` loop, you can just use `set.update` on an iterable:

```py
class Parser(ParserInterface):
    ~snip~
        
    def parse(self) -> None:
        # no need for the 'r' mode, as it's the default
        with open(self.filename) as fh:
            self.tokens.update((line.rstrip() for line in fh))
```

### `TextToMySQLConverter.write_on_file`

To write the `set` to the file, simply use `str.join`:

```py
    def write_on_file(self, filename: str = '') -> None:
        if not filename:
            raise Exception('Filename cannot be empty!')

        with open(filename, 'w') as file:
            file.write('\n'.join(self.queries))
```

### Bug: `converter`

I think you meant to have `self.converter` in `Manager.process`, otherwise it's relying on a global:

```py
    def process(self):
        self.parser.parse()
        tokens = self.parser.tokens

        # Here
        converter.setTokens(tokens)
        converter.convert(self.tableName, self.columnName)

        converter.writeOnFile(self.outputFilename)
```

### Getters and Setters

The `Manager` class should be able to take `output_filename`, `table_name`, and `column_name` as parameters, since you seem to know these ahead of time. This way you don't need the getter and setter methods:

```py
class Manager:
    def __init__(
        self, 
        output_filename: str,
        table_name: str,
        column_name: str,
        parser: ParserInterface, # Make these required
        converter: ConverterInterface
    ) -> None:
        self.parser = parser
        self.converter = converter
        self.output_filename = output_filename
        self.table_name = table_name
        self.column_name = column_name

    def process(self):
        self.parser.parse()
        self.converter.tokens = self.parser.tokens
        self.converter.convert(self.table_name, self.column_name)

        self.converter.write_file(self.output_filename)
```

However, now we have a class with two methods, one of which is `__init__`. This means that we should be able to safely convert this into a standalone function:

```py
def parse_and_write(
    parser: ParserInterface,
    converter: ConverterInterface,
    output_filename: str,
    table_name: str,
    column_name: str
):
    parser.parse()
    converter.tokens = parser.tokens
    converter.convert(table_name, column_name)

    converter.write_file(output_filename)
```

### `converter.tokens = parser.tokens`

IMO, `parser.tokens` should just be an argument to `converter.convert`:

```py
class TextToMySQLConverter(ConverterInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tokens = set()
        self.queries = set()

    def convert(self, tokens: set[str], tablename: str, columnname: str) -> None:
        for token in tokens:
            query = 'INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ("{2}");'.format(tablename, columnname, token)
            self.queries.add(query)
```

Now, this can also be refactored in the same way. Instead of returning `None`, return `queries`:

```py
def convert_tokens(self, tokens: set[str], tablename: str, columnname: str) -> set[str]:
    queries = set()

    for token in tokens:
        query = 'INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ("{2}");'.format(tablename, columnname, token)
        queries.add(query)

    return queries
```

What about `write_to_file`? That is a function as well, we aren't carrying around state, and it's just as easy to provide `queries` and `output_filename` as arguments:

```py
def write_queries(file: str, queries: set[str]) -> None:
    with open(file, 'w') as fh:
        fh.write('\n'.join(queries))
```

### `Parser`

As above, so below. `Parser` is also just a single function:

```py
def parse(filename: str) -> set[str]:
    with open(filename) as file:
        return set((line.rstrip() for line in file))
```

### `main` function

Now, your `process` function is really just a `main`:

````py
def parse(filename: str) -> set[str]:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return set((line.rstrip() for line in file))


def convert_tokens(tokens: set[str], tablename: str, columnname: str) -> set[str]:
    queries = set()

    for token in tokens:
        query = 'INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ("{2}");'.format(tablename, columnname, token)
        queries.add(query)

    return queries


def write_queries(file: str, queries: set[str]) -> None:
    with open(file, 'w') as fh:
        fh.write('\n'.join(queries))


def main(input_file: str, output_file: str, table_name: str, column_name: str):
    tokens = parse(input_file)
    
    queries = convert_tokens(tokens)

    write_queries(queries=queries, file=output_file)

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(
        input_file='original.txt',
        output_file='queries.txt',
        table_name='tablename',
        column_name='columnname'
    )
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## pass

```
class ParserInterface(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def parse(self) -> None:
        pass
```

At the end there we *had* to write `pass`,
something we generally avoid unless it's syntactically necessary.

You twice passed up the opportunity to """describe""" the
[responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
of the class or method.
Now for the class, no big deal, it seems pretty self explanatory.
But the method is a little surprising.

Typically I would expect a "parse" verb to consume
some ugly text and return it as a beautiful data structure.
But here the helpful annotation is explaining that we
must be evaluating for side effects.
Ok, fair enough.
But then explain those side effects in a docstring, please.
And having done that, there's no longer a necessity for that `pass`.

Similar remarks for `convert()`.

## default args

```
    def convert(self, tablename: str = '', columnname: str = '') -> None:
    ...
    def writeOnFile(self, filename: str = '') -> None:
```

The type annotation is helpful, thank you.
(I *am* sad the file name is of `str`
rather than the more natural `Path`.)

I can't imagine how those empty-string defaults
would be helpful to a caller.
Seems more likely that someone would use your Public API
incorrectly, then be lulled into a sense of false confidence
in the results due to lack of diagnostic exception being raised.
Consider leaving them as type `str`, with no default,
so caller is forced to supply a value.

Similarly with the `Parser` ctor.
Testing with `if not filename:` and then raising
is just silly, elide that part.
What you *might* sensibly do is insist on `Path`,
and `raise` unless `filename.exists()`.

Similarly down in `TextToMySQLConverter` and `Manager`.

And if you're going to `raise`,
either define an app-specific exception
or choose an appropriate one such as `ValueError`.
Avoid raising `Exception`,
as that prevents callers from focusing a `try` block
on an expected issue that they know how to recover from.

## lint

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you name it `write_on_file()`.

Similarly for `set_tokens()`.

## open() defaults

```
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as file:
```

Using a context handler for auto-close is beautiful, thank you.

nit: The `'r'` mode is default and might be elided.
If you're keen to tack on open() options,
you might consider `, encoding='utf8'`.
Personally I wouldn't, but some folks
assert it should always be specified
for fear of the system default being Latin1
or some crazy thing.
The systems I work on have a sensible unicode system default,
so the concern seldom arises.

```
            while line := file.readline():
                self.tokens.add(line.rstrip())
```

Sure, it works, and it's walrussy.
But please don't do that.
Stick to idiomatic consumption of the iterable:

```
            for line in file:
                ...
```

Hmmm, we have a lot of calls to `.add()`:

```
                self.tokens.add(line.rstrip())
```

Consuming the iterable could simply be done by `set()`:

```
        with open(self.filename) as file:
            self.tokens = set(map(str.rstrip, file))
```

## mutable default parameter

Please don't do this:

```
    def setTokens(self, tokens: set = set()) -> None:
```

This is valid syntax, but it has surprising results
likely to trip up a future maintenance engineer.
Therefore we don't write code like this, not ever,
without adding a helpful `#` comment
that offers a warning to the unwary.

SO supplies
[answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)
describing the effect.

The idiomatic way to write this would be:

```
    def set_tokens(self, tokens: set | None = None) -> None:
        self.tokens = tokens or set()
```

So instead of evaluating `set()` just once, "at compile time"
when the class is being parsed into bytecode,
for N calls we will evaluate `set()` N times, "at run time".
And yes, I know, the Optional aspect is annoying and ugly,
sorry about it, that's life.

## little Bobby Tables

```
    query = 'INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ("{2}");'.format(tablename, columnname, token)
```

Ugghh! Say it isn't so!

Maybe you have a Requirements Document that patiently
explains your input file shall only contain lowercase "a" .. "z"
characters and newlines.
I don't care.
Eventually some maintenance engineer will
[trip](https://xkcd.com/327) over this, hard.
Don't do it.
Use bind variables, as the DB vendor intended.
Do not attempt to merge this feature branch to `main`
in its current state.

(BTW, ever wonder why so many URLs include base64 encoded args?
Because someone's requirements document said that inputs
shall never include `&` ampersand, `?` question mark, `#` hash,
and similar punctuation. Until things changed.
So we defensively build for robustness, anticipating changes.)

nit: An INSERT is a DML "statement" with side effects,
not a side effect free "query".
If you don't like `statement`,
then a vague but accurate `sql` identifier would suffice.

## print

```
                file.write('{0}\n'.format(query))
```

nit: That's a curiously long way to write `print(query, file=file)`.
And when you feel the need to `.format()`,
usually it's better to write an f-string: `f"{query}\n"

## setters

```
    def setOutputFilename(self, filename: str = '') -> None: ...
        self.outputFilename = filename
```

I don't understand the rationale, here.
This isn't java, we don't need to define
a `set_output_filename()` routine,
when we have a **public** `self.output_filename` attribute.
Just assign to it.

If we change our mind,
we can always interpose a setter routine later,
perhaps for logging or for rejecting non-existent filenames.

Similarly for those other public attributes.

Aaannnddd, given that we can't really do anything
with attributes missing, wouldn't you like
the `__init__` ctor to insist that caller provides
them from the get go?

## batch size

It wasn't obvious to me how often you issue a COMMIT to the DB backend,
and the Review Context didn't comment on performance.

Sometimes a single BEGIN; INSERT; ... INSERT; END transaction suffices.
For a large ETL task we sometimes prefer to send a thousand
or ten thousand rows at a time, with a COMMIT between batches.

What you definitely want to avoid is an ETL
that does COMMIT after each INSERT.
That will slow things down without offering any app-level benefits.
An auto-commit setting of True will sometimes
arrange for more COMMITs than a code author intended.

## SQLAlchemy

There's more than one ORM that could help you
with this INSERT task. Consider using
[SQL Alchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core) for it.

## summary

1. Write injection-free code, always.
2. Avoid mutable default parameters.
3. Think carefully about whether a class or method is truly so well-named, so self-explanatory, that it needs no docstring. (Sometimes we don't need one, but less often than you think.)
4. Gather mandatory parameter values up front.
5. Embrace `Path`.
6. Choose snake_case identifiers.
7. Only write {get,set}ters for `_private` attributes.
8. Raise specific errors rather than generic `Exception`.

---

This codebase appears to accomplish many of its design goals.

There are enough design issues and code defects in the code
that I would not be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks
for it in its current form.